# Renaming a C++ thread when running under Visual Studio 2010 extension package

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm using the following code (from MSDN) to rename a C++ thread:

```
#include <windows.h>
const DWORD MS_VC_EXCEPTION=0x406D1388;

#pragma pack(push,8)
typedef struct tagTHREADNAME_INFO
{
   DWORD dwType; // Must be 0x1000.
   LPCSTR szName; // Pointer to name (in user addr space).
   DWORD dwThreadID; // Thread ID (-1=caller thread).
   DWORD dwFlags; // Reserved for future use, must be zero.
} THREADNAME_INFO;
#pragma pack(pop)

void SetThreadName( DWORD dwThreadID, char* threadName)
{
   THREADNAME_INFO info;
   info.dwType = 0x1000;
   info.szName = threadName;
   info.dwThreadID = dwThreadID;
   info.dwFlags = 0;

   __try
   {
      RaiseException( MS_VC_EXCEPTION, 0, sizeof(info)/sizeof(ULONG_PTR), (ULONG_PTR*)&info );
   }
   __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
   {
   }
}
```

And it is working great overall. However, when trying to execute this code in Visual Studio (2010) extension package, I get the following unhanded exception and the name of the thread doesn't change:

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException occurred
Message: External component has thrown an exception.**

Anyone has any clue what's going on there? I realize there might be some issues with changing a thread that way from extensions, however, it is undocumented and it seems to be working fine from a standard add-in.

Thanks!

Comment: The debugger needs to see this exception, the first-chance notification takes care of that.  There is no debugger attached to devenv.exe when you run this in an extension.  Not sure why the CLR steps in.

Comment: Interesting. However, there WAS a debugger attached when that happened. I was, in fact, debugging it with another devenv.exe session as that hapened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain whether this is the cause of your problem but according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs.aspx) MSDN documentation the `SetThreadName` function only applies to native code. Judging from the exception you're seeing you're compiling with the `/clr` option so you should probably use the managed code equivalent of this. Follow the link under the *See Also* section in the first link, it shows the snippet to use for managed code.

HTH,
Ashish.

Comment: Eventually I chose to simply comment out the thread renaming, but your way seems to be working as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds familiar.  Here's what the insides of our `SetThreadName` looks like (in a mixed native C++, C++/CLI, C# app):

```
#pragma warning(disable: 6312 6322)
        __try
        {
            RaiseException( 0x406D1388, 0, sizeof(info) / sizeof(DWORD), (DWORD*)&info );
        }
        // don't implement MSDN's suggested fix for 6312 here - it causes a nasty unhandled exception
        // to bubble up into managed code. Disable the compiler warning instead.
        __except(EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION)
        {
        }
#pragma warning(default: 6312 6322)
```